# Cannot find ButterKnife.bind in Butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

I include the butterknife library in my project

> implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'

*************UPDATE********
Added annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1' still not work.

It shows the following error message when building

> 21:26:51.121 [ERROR] [system.err] E:\workspace\company\git\shopglobal\android\Smart\app\src\main\java\com\package\smart\scenenew\actiivity\SmartActivity.java:150: 错误: 找不到符号
>
> 21:26:51.121 [ERROR] [system.err]         ButterKnife.bind(this);
>
> 21:26:51.121 [ERROR] [system.err]                    ^
>
> 21:26:51.121 [ERROR] [system.err]   符号:   方法 bind(SmartActivity)

But strangely I can view the source code in the android studio, and the ButterKnife jar is in the right place:

> .gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\butterknife-9.0.0-rc1.aar

It shows normal.

[image]

Comment: can you mention gradle file?

Comment: Don't use ButterKnife.
Use DataBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, you only added the library and not the annotation processor. Add this 
  `annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'` to your gradle file - preferably beneath your Butterknife dependency. Build your project.

Your Butterknife library should look like this:

```
dependencies {
  ....
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Added the annotationProcessor following the instruction. But still cannot find ButterKnife.bind.....It can resolve the @BindView, but cannot find the ButterKnife.bind method. I invalidate the cache and clean the project. Still not work...Very strange

Comment: I found why this happened. There exists a 3rd module, which adds a butterknife library. It puts the old-version butterknife jar under its libs dir, not imports from the gradle....sorry for that. Thank you!